# Problemas para validar pago con webpay de prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Buen día a todos,

Tengo un problema al validar un pago en una tienda online que estoy desarrollando. Levante 'prestashop' v1.6.1.6 e instale el plugin de webpay plus 1.1.2. Todo esto lo levante en un xampp v1.7.1, con PHP v5.2.9 y Mysql v5.1.33 y apache v2.2.11.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle continuar, me arroja el mensaje;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizando varias pruebas en Firefox, sin ningún problema, pero cuando cambie a realizar las pruebas en Chrome, me salió esto.

Lo extraño, es que en la cuenta 'admin' me aparece el pedido, validado.
He leído un montón de foros y al parecer no existe solución para esto.

Ojalá podamos resolverlo. Quedo atento a cualquier comentario.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!
Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Algunos modulos de pago necesitan instanciar la clase Order y Cart. Cuando esto ocurre hay una validacion que no permite que con el mismo carrito de compras se registren 2 pedidos. Si el modulo de pago previamente ya registro el pedido, y luego instancia nuevamente la clase (quizas para recargar los datos de la clase Order o para llamar alguna funcion con los datos actualizados) entonces se producira este problema. En realidad no deberia interferir con el normal funcionamiento del metodo de pago.

Buena suerte.

Comment: Estimado @PrestaAlba GRACIAS por tu respuesta, pero no me queda muy claro. No me queda claro, el porqué falla con el navegador Chrome. Incluso lo probé con IE sin problemas. Como dices no influye en el funcionamiento del método de pago, pero si le arroja el mensaje al usuario y se ve como un error. Se me ocurre que se agregue un contador que permita cambiar el ID del carrito para que no quede registrado el mismo carrito con dos pedidos, podría ser..?

Comment: Olvidaba comentar, que al realizar varias compras (siempre en Chrome), al refrescar las cookies (es decir, limpiarlas) el flujo se completa sin el mensaje y vuelve a la confirmación del pedido. También utilizo un 'cleaner' de prestashop que limpia toda configuración existente, usuarios e historiales (que no es muy recomendable usar..). Pero lo de las cookies, es un buen punto, para analizar. GRACIAS! Quedo atento..

Comment: Yo no te recomendaria cambiar el ID del carrito desde programacion, porque pudiera afectar el funcionamiento normal del proceso de compra. Si nada mas sucede con un navegador entonces la solucion deberia ser puntual para ese navegador que quizas por un problema de compatbilidad debe estar fallando. Si fueras a tocar algo en el codigo yo te recomendaria eliminar o poner en null el id_cart de la cookie al finalizar el proceso de compra. Creo que seria la opcion menos invasiva y mas simple de probar.

Comment: Tambien podrias buscar la ubicacion exacta donde se lanza este error y hacerle un override a la clase para que cuando sea el modulo webpay y el navegador chrome no lance este error. Buena suerte